# SQL ALTER TABLE with default

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to alter a table in Oracle. I have to give a column in a table a default value of `1`. This is simple enough when making the table but I have to do it using the `ALTER TABLE` feature, This is what I have:

```
 ALTER TABLE Stock_Qty
 ADD CONSTRAINT Qty_DEFAULT_Value DEFAULT (Qty 1);
```

It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is a trivial syntax question.  As @ta.speot.is points out, you could answered this for yourself by reading Oracle's documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE Stock_Qty
MODIFY Qty DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been trying for over an hour with this!

Comment: @user1756421 In future you could look at Oracle's documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2133121 *Specifying Default Column Value: Examples* is pretty clear.

Comment: You are welcome. On SO, when you receive a correct answer, click the Accept button since it increases your accept-rate percentage and adds 2 points to your reputation. I know syntax diagrams can be frightening, but recommend you get comfortable using them to save time and grief as @user1756421 suggested.